# Build array from results of filtered array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I got an array with facebook posts, but I have a limit on the number of posts AND a check which checks if the message isn't empty and if the post was made by the page owner.

How can I filter out those results from the first array, and build a new array from that data? Because limiting the first array is not an option, it also counts the wrong messages (by other than page owner, edited profile pictures etc).

My code now (relevant parts):

```
$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$f = 0;

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{

    if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
        $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
    }else{
        $fbimage = 'cms/images/placeholder/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    if($feed_data->message > 270){
    $shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 270) . '...';
    }else{
        $shortstrfb = $feed_data->message;
    }

    if($feed_data->message != ''){
        $f++;
    }

    if($f > 2){
        break;
    }

    if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'page owner'){
        $facebookfeed .= '
                <div class="col-lg-4 marg-lg-b30">
                    <div class=" widget">
                        <div class="card latest-news latest-news--block">
                            <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" class="latest-news__image">
                                <img src="'.$fbimage.'" width="360" height="204" srcset="'.$fbimage.' 360w, '.$fbimage.' 830w" sizes="(min-width: 992px) 360px, calc(100vw - 30px)" class="card-img-top " alt="nieuws">
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-block latest-news__content js-col-height-news">
                                <time class="latest-news__date">'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time)).'</time>
                                <h4 class="card-title latest-news__title">
                                    <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> Bekijk</a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="card-text latest-news__text">
                                    '.$shortstrfb.'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
}
echo $facebookfeed;
```

As you can see I check all those things on `$feedarray` while I probably need to check on it, and from the results build a new array which I can use like I want. What is a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a new array and append your loop result in it and at the end check its content with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) :

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{

    if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
        $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
    }else{
        $fbimage = 'cms/images/placeholder/placeholder.jpg';
    }

    if($feed_data->message > 270){
    $shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 270) . '...';
    }else{
        $shortstrfb = $feed_data->message;
    }

    if($feed_data->message != ''){
        $f++;
    }

    if($f > 2){
        break;
    }

    if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'page owner'){
        $facebookfeed .= '
                <div class="col-lg-4 marg-lg-b30">
                    <div class=" widget">
                        <div class="card latest-news latest-news--block">
                            <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" class="latest-news__image">
                                <img src="'.$fbimage.'" width="360" height="204" srcset="'.$fbimage.' 360w, '.$fbimage.' 830w" sizes="(min-width: 992px) 360px, calc(100vw - 30px)" class="card-img-top " alt="nieuws">
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-block latest-news__content js-col-height-news">
                                <time class="latest-news__date">'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time)).'</time>
                                <h4 class="card-title latest-news__title">
                                    <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> Bekijk</a>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="card-text latest-news__text">
                                    '.$shortstrfb.'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }

    // build the new array : 
    $new_array[] = array(
        'fbimage' => $fbimage,
        'shortstrfb' => $shortstrfb,
        'facebookfeed' => $facebookfeed
    );
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Hope it helps.